# JavaScript hide/show div function

Tags: javascript, css

Since this morning my function to show/hide specific divs is not working anymore. Everything was fine yesterday and my code doesn't seem to have any error:

l2ace.js file:

```
function showShop(id)
{
if(document.getElementById('paypal-form')){document.getElementById('paypal-form').style.display='none';}
if(document.getElementById('paysafecard-form')){document.getElementById('paysafecard-form').style.display='none';}
if(document.getElementById('allopass-form')){document.getElementById('allopass-form').style.display='none';}
if(document.getElementById(id)){document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';}
}
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper #shop-member #paypal-form {display:block;}
#wrapper #shop-member #paysafecard-form {display:none;}
#wrapper #shop-member #allopass-form {display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/l2ace.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="shop-member"><h1>Shop</h1>
  <a class="paypal" href="" onclick="showShop('paypal-form');return false;"></a>
  <a class="paysafecard" href="" onclick="showShop('paysafecard-form');return false;"></a>
  <a class="allopass" href="" onclick="showShop('allopass-form');return false;"></a>

  <div id="paypal-form"><form action="" method="post">a</form></div>
  <div id="paysafecard-form"><form action="" method="post">b</form></div>
  <div id="allopass-form"><form action="" method="post">c</form></div>
</div>
```

All is working when I inject the javascript function right behind the "shop-member" div but not if I import it from page header. Unfortunately I cannot place it after the div or my slider module will print the script in plain text so I really need to make it work from the header as it worked yesterday.

Demo at https://www.l2ace.com/ username: test  password: test

When clicking the buttons, we clearly see the width of the divs changing but the content doesn't change.

Comment: where have you given the external script tag inside head tag ?

Comment: The function is located inside /js/l2ace.js and the import from the head looks like:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/l2ace.js"></script>

I'm using Joomla but anyway the script is correctly imported

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript inside `<script></script>` and it will never print in the screen.
Also if you want your js code from external path then use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/yourjs.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I already did that but even with the <script> tags, my slider module print it in plain text

Comment: Can you put console.log() in you js method in l2ace.js? Check if its get printed or not.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your latest reply. Can you put `style.display = '';`

Comment: I made some tests and saw it's coming from a conflict with the slider module. When I remove it it works perfectly

Comment: Can you share the code where it might be conflicting and may be I can help figure it out? in you slider module that is.

Comment: I use this one: http://liquidslider.com/
But yesterday there was no conflicts, I don't understand...

Comment: Okay so did you changed anything after yesterday. I think there's no point in digging the code if it was working earlier.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'adjustHeight' ` .Please take a look at this error in jquery.liquid-slider.js. As it is minified I'm not able to get the exact line#.

Comment: This error was here forever, I don't think it's coming from there. Now I managed to make all work but the script is printed on the page after shop. The slider created a new slide

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put that code inside your window load event?

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('load', function () {
    new JCaption('img.caption');

    //Your function here
    function showShop(id) {
        if (document.getElementById('paypal-form')) {
            document.getElementById('paypal-form').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (document.getElementById('paysafecard-form')) {
            document.getElementById('paysafecard-form').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (document.getElementById('allopass-form')) {
            document.getElementById('allopass-form').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (document.getElementById(id)) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Or inside the `$(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/});`

Comment: I don't see the point of changing the loading of the function because it's correctly loaded, the buttons are reactive but the printed div doesn't change! You should try the demo on live site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put `<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/l2ace.js"></script>` before your slider module js at the header?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/l2ace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="shop-member"><h1>Shop</h1>
  <a class="paypal" href="#">PayPal</a>
  <a class="paysafecard" href="#">PaySafecard</a>
  <a class="allopass" href="#">Allopass</a>

  <div id="paypal-form"><form action="" method="post">a</form></div>
  <div id="paysafecard-form"><form action="" method="post">b</form></div>
  <div id="allopass-form"><form action="" method="post">c</form></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//onclick paypal class
$('.paypal').click(function(){
    $('#paypal-form').show();

    $('#paysafecard-form').hide();
    $('#allopass-form').hide();
});

$('.paysafecard').click(function(){
    $('#paysafecard-form').show();

    $('#paypal-form').hide();
    $('#allopass-form').hide();
});

$('.allopass').click(function(){
    $('#allopass-form').show();

    $('#paypal-form').hide();

    $('#paysafecard-form').hide();
});
</script>
```